# Merge multiple PDF files into one with PHP Ghostscript

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to merge multiple PDF files on my server using Ghostscript with the following code :

```
$files = array(
        '1.pdf',
        '2.pdf',
        '3.pdf'
);

$output = 'single.pdf';

$cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$output ";

foreach($files as $file)
    $cmd .= "pdfs/$file ";

var_dump(shell_exec($cmd));
```

The script that I use is in the root folder and the PDF files are in a folder named *pdfs* :

```
/[pdfs]
|__ 1.pdf
|__ 2.pdf
|__ 3.pdf
script.php
```

The permissions for the folders and files are all `777`.

But despite all this, nothing is happening and the returned value is `NULL`.

So what am I doing wrong ? What is the exact way to merge multiple PDF files into one using Ghostscript ?

Comment: Have you tried echoing $cmd instead of executing it, so you can copy it and paste it into a terminal to verify the command is valid and working?

Comment: I can try it but which terminal I would use then ? I've just checked my server and I saw that the PDF files were finally merged and the output result is correct. I haven't done anything since my last test. So I think that it could be just a matter of time. Is there a way to calculate how long it could take ?

Answer (score 3):

Just a side comment; Ghostscript does **not** 'merge' PDF files, it can take multiple PDF files as an input and create a brand new PDF file whose visual appearance should be the same as the inputs, but it isn't merging the PDF files, the input is fully interpreted and the new file has nothing other than appearance in common with the input files.

So, are you certain Ghostscript is working properly ?
Have you tried processing a single PDF file ? 
Does it work ?

If not then the most likely problem is that you don't have the directory containing the Ghostscript executable in your $PATH environment variable (this is a common problem). You can test this by supplying a fully qualified path to the Ghostscript executable in your command line, so instead of:

```
$cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$output ";
```

Try something like :

```
$cmd = "/usr/local/bin/gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$output ";
```

Obviously you will have to modify the path to match your setup. If that works, then the problem is likely to be that the directory isn't in $PATH, you can either add it or just use the full path.

There is also a logical error I can't help you with;

It looks to me like your 'foreach' is going to invoke cmd once for each of the files in the array. That means each file is going to be processed by a call to Ghostscript. So each file will produce a separate PDF file. Since they are all using the same OutputFile, they will overwrite each other.

If you want a single output to be created using the input of all the files, you need to call Ghostscript exactly **once**, not once per input file, and the command line needs to include all of the input files.

In essence what you have now is:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=single.pdf 1.pdf
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=single.pdf 2.pdf
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=single.pdf 3.pdf
```

What you want is:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=single.pdf 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf
```

Since I know nothing about PHP I can't tell you how to correct that.

Comment: Well, first thank you for your detailed comment but your approach is wrong as the `foreach` does not invoke the command for each file but it just concatenates the string variable `$cmd`. Ghostscript is called with the method `shell_exec` and it's done only once at the end of the script. In fact, my problem was solved and it was just a matter of time. I waited a few more minutes and the output PDF file was there.

Comment: Well I did say I wasn't a PHP developer :-)